# In SharePoint 2007, how can I change the background color of the Web Part Zone?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2007, cewp

I know I can change the background color of a Web Part by including CSS in the source of a Content Editor Web Part:

```
<style type="text/css">
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3{
background-color:"#ddecff";
}
</style>
```

But I would like to change the background color for the entire Web Part Zone. White is very boring... Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not familiar with SharePoint 2007, but can't you just target the DOM body or the ID of the part part zone?

Comment: Probably. I don't know what it's called though. I've scanned through the page source, but with 700+ lines, it's hard to pick it out. I was hoping someone would know.

Comment: can you dump your entire HTML page on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-chrome-title
{
background-color: Gray;
}

.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText, .ms-webpart-titleText > a 
{
color: White!important;
}
</style>​​​​​
```